# Start working at age 58. What's probable pension amount?

Tags: united-states, pension, form-1099

My dad (58 years old) recently received US Green Card. He is working now as an independent contractor (truck driver) in Pennsylvania state and gets **1099** form at the end of the year. CPA office, where all our family does taxes, deducts a static amount of **$2000** out of his yearly income (which is around 50K-55K) towards IRS.

Once retired, what's the monthly pension amount he can consider to receive? What can be done to increase this amount?How about asking CPA office to deduct more? Thanks for your valuable opinions.

**Addition**: The reason I asked this question is one of my friend's mother came to US on the approved Green Card at the age of 54, and for the next 5 year has worked as a weekend speaker on one of the Christian radio. She was not getting paid so well for the job, but after retire, she is having around $650 pension monthly payments. Assumption: you don't have to work too long to get a pension payments in the country.

Comment: Your terms are confusing (or I'm misinterpreting them). If "towards IRS" means "towards an IRA", then there is no defined benefit amount (IRAs are not the same as pensions). the amount of income and/or growth will be entirely dependent on what investments he has in the IRA.

Comment: @DStanley No, I literally meant to IRS(Internal Revenue Service). Isn't the IRS who later define pension amount based on the paid taxes?

Comment: Your dad must have been a permanent resident of the US for at least 5 years in order to be qualified to apply for naturalization as a US citizen. What was he working on then? Was Social Security tax withheld from his income during those years, or was he self-employed during that time too? In the US, there is no national pension scheme. There _are_ Social Security benefits, but those will be small if your father began paying Social Security taxes fairly recently.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Apologies, I edited the question. Dad actually granted Green Card, not naturalized.

Comment: Why down voting? Any questions? I'll clarify

Comment: Are you referring to Social Security? Pensions usually refer to a defined-benefit plan provided by a company, not the US government.To be eligible for SS you need to have worked and paid into it for 40 quarters (10 years). If he is an independent contractor, I think he'd have to file Schedule SE, and pay 15.3% of his 1099 income, which would be considerably more than $2000. And that's in addition to any normal income taxes. I'm not sure if it's different for Permanent Residents than citizens, but I don't think so.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you don't have to be a citizen to get Social Security retirement benefits, you just need the 10 years of US employment (with an employer/self employment that withholds SS). This individual should be eligible if they work until they are 68 ***OR*** earlier if they come from a country that has a [totalization agreement](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/030816/immigrants-over-65-and-social-security-benefits.asp) with the US and they paid into that country's SS equivalent.

Comment: @CactusCake  I never claimed that one needs to be a citizen to get SS benefits. My response was to the **original** version of the question where the OP claimed that his father because _naturalized_ a short while ago, and wondered what kind of pension he would get. The US doesn't _have_ pensions; only SS benefits, and the OP seemed to believe that his father began paying SS taxes only upon becoming a citizen.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after it was too late to edit the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Green Card holders are eligible for social security benefits if they earn 40 Social Security credits (this is a requirement for citizens too), at most you can earn 4 per year, so need a minimum of 10 years working to qualify.

He'll pay federal income tax and, since an independent contractor, self-employment tax to the IRS, self-employment tax covers Medicare and social security.

The main things he can do to increase social security benefits are earning more money and delaying retirement (it's not an investment vehicle that you can throw more money at). To invest in retirement he should probably open a SIMPLE IRA or similar.

There are calculators to estimate Social Security benefit, the [SSA's Quick Calculator](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/quickcalc/) doesn't handle the scenario in question very well because it errors if there aren't 40 credits by minimum drawing age.

Comment: so there is no simple formula that calculates Social Security pension amount based on the paid taxes correct? Better to open an IRA account and deduct in it...

Comment: in 10 years he will be a citizen. So no need to fight for those 40 credits?

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming Updated to address, there are calculators for social security benefits (not a pension plan) and the 40 credits is a requirement for citizens too.

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming: There is a formula, but it is not simple.  Go to the Social Security Administration web site, and you will find a number of calculators: https://www.ssa.gov/planners/calculators/